# Gmail Java Api - limiting search by "newer_than:"

Tags: gmail-api

Gmail Java Api doesn't limit message search to 60 days. Also is there a way to enable debug to see actual API call?

```
ListMessagesResponse messagesResponse = gmailService.users().messages().list(USER).setQ("CATEGORY:PROMOTIONS newer_than:60d").setMaxResults(100l).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
category:promotions after:2014/11/3
```

... is the query you want. You'll have to generate the date based on todays date minus 60 days. Looks like you're using java so I'd recommend Joda time to do the 60 day subtraction.

Here's how you can enable logging debug information to be printed out: https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#java_log

Comment: The logging FAQ you linked to is for the older GData client library. This is the link for the newer Google APIs Client library: https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/HTTP#Logging